# How can I get partition mounted ? "mount: /Volumes/mytest failed with 71"

Tags: macos, mount, partition

The exfat partition of my external drive is not mounted automatically on my mac.
I created a /mytest directory in the /Volumes directory and tried to mount it, but I get the following error and cannot mount it.
This works for everything else, but I cannot mount this partition.
How can I get it mounted?

```
sh-3.2# diskutil list rdisk7
/dev/disk7 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 TB     disk7
   1:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk7s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data myexfhdtosi             4.4 TB     disk7s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data                         1.6 TB     disk7s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS myhfshddtosi            1000.0 GB  disk7s4


sh-3.2# mount -v  -t exfat  /dev/rdisk7s2 /Volumes/mytest
mount_exfat: /dev/rdisk7s2 on /Volumes/mytest: Block device required
mount: /Volumes/mytest failed with 71
```

Comment: The identifier is `disk7s2`, without the `r`. Typo?

Comment: ```sh-3.2# mount -t exfat /dev/disk7s2 /Volumes/mytest
mount_exfat: /dev/disk7s2 on /Volumes/mytest: Invalid argument
mount: /Volumes/mytest failed with 71
```

Comment: It didn't work even without the "r".

Comment: ```~~ /Volumes % diskutil mount /dev/disk7s2        
Volume on disk7s2 failed to mount
If you think the volume is supported but damaged, try the "readOnly" option
~~ /Volumes %
~~ /Volumes % diskutil mount readonly /dev/disk7s2 
Volume on disk7s2 failed to mount
If you think the volume is supported but damaged, try the "readOnly" option
```

Answer (score 1):

Try killing the `fsck` service and mount again.

```
sudo pkill -f fsck
```

See this [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293390/macos-cant-mount-exfat-external-drive) for detail discussion.